# Get subpages using pre_get_posts

Tags: wordpress, loops

I am creating a website using wordpress and I have a portfolio page in which I display all the portfolio items -which are made of subpages of the parent page 'portfolio'.
To display the subpages and their content on the portfolio parent page, I need a special query.
To do this I simply create a page template for the portfolio page. On it I queried the database as follows:

```
$parent = post->ID; //portfolio page ID
query_posts('post_type=page&post_parent='.$parent);//grab those children of portfolio
```

Wonderful. However I learned over time that its better to use pre_get_posts for such a job as it is less taxing on the server and on wordpress.
Harder, but possible:

```
function portfolioloop($query){

if ($query->is_page( 'portfolio') ){//query will only effect my portfolio page

 $children = get_pages(array('child_of' => 35, 'echo' => 0) ); 
    // i dont think post->ID; works here. 
   //35 is the post ID of portfolio. Let me know if im wrong.

  // get and add the children id's to array. only id's is needed. 
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($children); ++$i) { 
  $portfolioitems[] = $children[$i]->ID; //$portfolioitems is a list of id's only. thats what we want
   } 

   $query->set('post__in', $portfolioitems);

 }


}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','portfolioLoop');
```

Alas, it returns page not found. What have I done wrong?
If you can help me, I would be so grateful
thank you,

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is that your final query has `name=portfolio` and then you add the `post__in`. And most-likely none of the pages that are `child_of=35` have the slug - therefore resulting in no posts found and an empty query. Now can you explain me how doing the exact same query helps your server(I don't mean to be rude or something, I'm just curious) - because `get_pages()` is an additional query to the database, so I don't see much of a difference between doing `get_pages()` in the `pre_get_posts` and `query_posts()` or `get_pages()` later.

Comment: well wordpress says its the 'preffered way' and most of the time you will query the database once. If you use query_posts you will query twice. Also Im not sure I understand your answer. the function is called if the portfolio page is beng viewed, but after that It shouldnt matter what pages I decide to show...should it?

Comment: I believe query_posts will query 3 times. Once beforeas the defualt. Than it will dump that info for query_posts. And it will Query a third time for pages. Pre_get_posts in this situation will query twice. I could be wrong of course... However why is this code not working? I still am at a loss.

Comment: I thought that `get_pages()` and `get_posts()` both use `WP_Query->query()`, but it turns out that `get_pages()` doesn't and that it has a caching mechanism. Any way - your problem(I think) is that, you're looking for a page with slug `portfolio`(this is the original query, that WP figured-out from the current URL) and then you set a limitation on this query(which should really return only one result), that the results should be included only if their ID's match the `$portfolioitems` array. Which for obvious reasons is really unlikely to happen.

Comment: But is_page('portfolio') isn't a query?  I thought get_pages will get pages no matter what the query was originally. So how do you suppose I fix this? I was able to list subpages before like this on my main blog page. Somehow here it wont work.

Comment: Oh i think I understand. So this only is triggered once it has queried portfolio. So how can I grab the subpages.... I have to requery somehow. So is pre_get_posts only good for search pages and the main loop? For pages it is not as easy to include  other subpages or post-types?

Comment: Yeah I think it's generally good for when you want to modify a query that gets a posts selection(like an archive page, search page, etc), but it's not good for single pages(be it a single post or a page). So I think you might want to make a custom Page template and use `get_pages()` on it to get the pages you want and display them.